# Pandas: Assign number based on populatrity

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
d = {'id': [1,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4], 'number': [3,3,3,1,4,6,4,5,5,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

I want to get a new dataframe with the columns "id" and "final_number", where each id is assigned to the most "popular" number within each group of id's form the table above. How can I do it ?

The result should be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `value_counts` + `head` -

```
df.groupby('id')\
  .number.value_counts()\
  .groupby(level=0)\
  .head(1)\
  .reset_index(name='count')\
  .drop('count', 1)

   id  number
0   1       3
1   3       4
2   4       5
```

Comment: Nice and readable ! One more question: If I have the following dataset: d = {'name': ['A','B','C'],'id': [1,3,4]} dn = pd.DataFrame(data=d) and I want to edit the "name" column such that each name is named as follows: "name_number (from the df dataset)". How can I do it ?

Comment: @james First, do `df2 = df.merge(dn, on='id')`, and then to get the new column, `df2['name'] = df2.name + '_' + df2.number.astype(str)`. Lastly, drop the number column: `df2 = df2.drop('number', 1)`

Answer (score 3):

the most "popular" number should be `mode`

```
df.groupby('id').number.apply(lambda x : x.mode()[0]).reset_index()

Out[1499]: 
   id  number
0   1       3
1   3       4
2   4       5
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Comment: @james you can do something like dn.name=dn.name+'_'+str(df.number)